# Copy/Paste entire XML document into a single SQL Server row

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I have a single SQL table

```
CREATE TABLE [QLTY].[PG_XML_F40E]
(
     [XML] [xml] NULL
)
```

That I want to contain the entirety of a XML document. Think copy/pasting XML document into a insert statement to the above table.

How can I do this in SSIS so that it is automated, versus manually copying XML, then pasting into a insert statement? The XML files are between 40-60 MB, so rather large but I am able to accomplish this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do it programmatically.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    XmlColumn XML
);

INSERT INTO @tbl(XmlColumn)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'e:\Temp\books.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```